# Difference between reactive (coherent) and dissipative coupling in open quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators, open-quantum-systems

I am unsure about the physical interpretation of the different types of coupling, I understand that reactive coupling is manifested by a term within the Hamiltonian and dissipative is via a term in the Lindblad master equation.

My understanding of a physical interpretation is that reactive coupling would be a mechanical oscillation between two different systems whereas dissipative coupling would be the exchange of energy through the environment between the two oscillators?

I would appreciate if somebody could go into more detail on this and perhaps give a useful reference as to where I can read up more on this, especially in the context of two quantum harmonic oscillators.

Comment: "Perhaps go into detail on this" is too vague for this site. Please check the help center for advice on how to write good questions that are likely to get good answers. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @DanielSank classic: "...is too vague for this site..."

Comment: @hyportnex Well it's better to tell the user *why* their question is not attracting answers, right? :-)

Comment: :( I thought the question was in the title...